# Should I named validate function throwExceptionIf...?

Tags: java, oop, naming-conventions

I have many private validate functions in the code that use the same naming convention validateSomething(). Some of them throw an exception if validate is failed. I going to re-named it throwExceptionIfSomethingInvalid() to make the code more readable. But someone argue that the new name is too strange and cause them confusing. Could you help to give me some advices about that?

Comment: Are the exceptions being thrown *checked* exceptions or *unchecked* exceptions *(runtime)*

Comment: It's all checked exception.

Comment: The name `throwExceptionIfSomethingInvalid` does not flow very well, but using `validateSomethingOrThrow` is basically the same as `validateSomething` just with the added explicit information that if validation fails it will throw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no "exact" answers here; only conventions. And which one you choose doesn't matter so much. The more important point is: whatever naming policy you choose:

1. You have to "stick" with that. Don't use one kind of "naming scheme" here, and another there.
2. In case you are working in a team with other people: make sure that **everybody** on the team has the **same** understanding of these policies.

In other words: you want to follow [POLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) (principle of least astonishment). Readers of your code should always find that the name of a method (in your context) does exactly say what the method will do.

Besides, "my policy" is typically that a **void** method that starts like `checkSomething` or `validateSomethingElse` will always throw an exception if the check fails (and well: what is could a void-method do besides throwing an exception).

In contrast to a **boolean** returning `isSomethingValid()` or so.

Answer (score 1):

> But someone argue that the new name is too strange

I agree. The right way to specify that your method can throw a checked exception is to declare it as part of the method signature. Examples :

1. `validateName()throws InvalidInputException`
2. `validateAge()throws InvalidInputException`

When you do this, the caller will always be forced to either handle the exception or propagate it to a higher module.

Another way to look at this would be to ask your self this : would you name a method that does not return any value `void doSomethingWithoutReturn`? No because you can know that the method does not return anything when you see that it's signature has `void` in it.

Comment: But the readers must find it in the function declare, not the function name itself. Not all validation functions throw exception, so when I met a invoking to validate function, I must find the declare to find it out, especially when reading code in not IDE environment.

Comment: @Nghia You can't go about naming methods like that just because you are not using an IDE. Let's say you have a method that is final : `final void someMethod()`. Are you going to rename this method to `void someMethodFinalWithNoReturn` because you don't use an IDE? No right?

Comment: Yes, I got your point. But the throwing exception is the main purpose of the validate function, I think it's different with final void. I also see some thing like errorIfClosed() in hibernate source,  it help me very much to understand the code. Have you see any function using that naming convention yet?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with a method called `errorIfClosed`; however, `throwExceptionIfSomethingInvalid()` is wrong since the method signature already contains a `throws` clause`.

Comment: Yes you are changing my mind. So if I change to errorIfSomethingInvalid(), does it make sense?

Comment: Depends on how you plan to call these methods.

Comment: This isn't necessarily the **right** way of doing things; it is just one way. And for the record: many people claim that in the war between checked and unchecked exceptions, unchecked won - because those throw statements have the ugly downside of easily polluting many of your interfaces. Me, I am nowadays mainly using RuntimeExceptions; and I put javadoc on such methods that tells the user about it. Just because I saw too much code where throw lists turned longer and longer, and pulled details from lower levels into many layers above them.

Comment: If your method is declaring that it can throw too many exceptions, then you are doing something wrong..